# Using Gumby, when I import a new custom scss file into gumby.scss, do I include an underscore?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, css-frameworks

I noticed that in the `gumby.scss` file, there is the line:

```
@import "custom";
```

... but the filename itself is `_custom.scss`.

For every file that I create after that, do I include the underscore?

As an example, if I create a file `_custom2.scss`, would I then use the import

```
@import "custom2";
```

or

```
@import "_custom2":
```

?

If it assumes that there will be an underscore in the file name, what are the rules for its assumptions?  Does it do that with all filenames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either.

A file that begins with an `_` is a [partial](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials) in Sass.

Basically, if you want it to generate its own `css` file, don't add the underscore. If you want to import it into another sass file, use the `_`.